# Flex & JS Login with facebook

Tags: authentication, facebook-authentication

I have an application in Flex and in the HTML file I have some javascript scripts. Javascript first login to Facebook and take some actions depending the user and configuration before loading the Flex application. Once all is ok, Flex app loads and login again to Facebook and here is the inconvenience. It appears a popup window from Facebook, remain for 2 or 3 seconds and close again.

Well, all work perfectly. The question is that we have noticed that browsers with the 'block pop up window' option enabled, do not let the login and the Flex app can not start as should.

Would you mind giving me an advice about what should I do for avoiding this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem. I only had to erase the login call within the Flex code. That's because I first login in Javascript.